# Regex select the last numbers after the /

Tags: regex

in this example

```
BIOLOGIQUES                                                             3433     130906 / 3842
```

to select 3433 I use

```
BIOLOGIQUES\s+(\d+)
```

But what changes should I do to select the last one 3842?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern like this:

```
BIOLOGIQUES\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+/\s+(\d+)
```

This will match:

- a literal `BIOLOGIQUES`
- one or more white space characters
- one or more digits, captured in group 1
- one or more white space characters
- one or more digits, captured in group 2
- one or more white space characters
- a literal `/`
- one or more white space characters
- one or more digits, captured in group 3

Given your example string, it will capture 3433, 130906, and 3842 in groups 1, 2, and 3 respectively. Don't forget, many regex engines use a forward slash to delimit regular expression literals (e.g. JavaScript), so you may need to escape the `/`:

```
/BIOLOGIQUES\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\/\s+(\d+)/
```

---

Of course if all you want is to find the 'last number after the `/`' in a string it's much easier. This would do the trick:

```
/.*?(\d+)\D*$
```

This will match

- a literal `/`
- zero or more of any character (non-greedily)
- one or more digits, captured in group 1
- zero or more non-digit characters
- the end of the string (or line in multi-line mode)

Comment: This will match the third sequence of digits, not the "last" one.

Comment: @pguardiario I provided a simple alternative which would satisfy that if is actually a requirement.

Comment: No, that one doesn't work because the .* is greedy. It should probably have been `/.*\b(\d+)`. The `\D*$` is not necessary because of .*'s greediness. Do you see it now? Anyway, @Anirudh got it first.

Comment: @pguardiario You're right about the greedyness, I've corrected that. There are many ways of solving "last number after the `/`", and the solution provided by *Anirudh* would work as well.

Comment: While I agree there is more that one away to solve, you have taken the  elegance of Anirudh's solution and added a bunch of unneccessary junk on top. The greediness of `.*` does the work for you. You can't see that? You should delete this answer and vote for Anirudh's.

Comment: @pguardiario I agree that there are more elegant solutions, however Anirudh's answer doesn't bother to give an explanation about *how* it works. IMHO, the explanation of an answer on SO is just as important, if not more so, than it's elegance, particularly when it comes to answers with the regex tag. You're welcome to downvote my answer if you disagree.

Comment: Ok, well maybe I'm crazy, but I think that the best answer should be the accepted answer. You changed your answer 3 times and its still not as good as @Anirudth's original answer, and I've explained this thing to death. So how about we call a truce and give this one to Anirudh? I don't see what you hope to gain by fighting over this. A few rep points when you already have 33K+?

Answer (score 1):

Use greedy quantifier

```
BIOLOGIQUES.*/.*\s(\d+)
```